# Earth leakage tripping with 3 phase motor

Tags: motor, vfd, leakage-current

I'm working in elevator world, i'm now in a strange situation.

The 3 Phase synchronous motor is connected by drive then main controller and a distribution board.

The  faulty earth leakage circuit breaker keeps tripping when the motor just start to rotate.

I disconnected the UVW wires that connect the VFD to the motor, and the break was released and the earth leakage didn't trip.

The problem is that after checking the coils of the motor (UVW) by the continuity test between them and the motor chassis, there was no contact between them.

What is the possible diagnosis for this situation?

Comment: Faulty earth leakage breaker?

Comment: Yes, Earth leakage circuit breaker.

Comment: And the word “faulty”....?

Comment: Oh yes the faulty earth leakage circuit breaker

Comment: So what do you think you should do with a faulty elcb?

Comment: I will try to change it, because i'm not sure 100% if it's faulty or not.

Comment: So get a tester and test it... current rating, leakage current and response time...

Comment: But what if the ELCB wasn't faulty, what would be the problem?

Comment: Eliminate that as a possible problem - anyone with experience would approach this logically...

Comment: Faulty cable between VFD and motor?

Answer (score 2):

VFD’s produce Common Mode noise that must be filtered.  Check for EMI and replace or add filter.

The goal is to have all the Common Mode Noise return to the VFD. Here are some actions that
will help reduce or eliminate the tripping of the GFCI. The motor cable should be VFD rated motor cable and the motor and shield should be grounded back to the VFD.

The GFCI measure current imbalance and not actual leakage to ground. So CM noise and imbalanced currents present the same symptom as ground fault leakage > x mA.